# Update variable in foreach

Tags: c#

I have an issue related to updating an object by reference and not sure exactly what is going on.

I need to delete a list of rules and for logging I need to load another field

```
ruleItem.ReferencedItemValue = eventEntity.Title;
```

When

```
 builder.LogDelete(showRule, showRuleResource.ToAuditLog(), "Logic Rule");
```

is called the `ReferencedItemValue` is not populated.

Any ideas, suggestions, alternatives?
Thanks

CODE:

```
public void DeleteCustomLogicRule(int[] ruleIds){
    var rules = uow.Context.ShowRules.Where(sr => ruleIds.Contains(sr.Id)).ToList();
    if (rules.Any())
    {
        var showId = rules.FirstOrDefault().ShowId;
        var builder = AuditBuilder.FromShowId(showId);
        rules.ForEach(showRule =>
        {
            var showRuleResource = ToShowRuleResource(showRule);
            FillReferenceValue(showRuleResource);
            builder.LogDelete(showRule, showRuleResource.ToAuditLog(), "Logic Rule");
            });
        uow.Context.SaveChanges();
        builder.ToDatabase();
    }
}

private void FillReferenceValue(ShowRuleResource showRuleResource)
{
    foreach (var ruleItem in showRuleResource.ItemsPredicateAppliesTo.ToList())
    {
        FillRuleItem(ruleItem);
    }
}

private void FillRuleItem(RuleItemResource ruleItem)
{
    var eventEntity = uow.Context.Events.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == ruleItem.ReferencedItemId.Value);
    if (eventEntity != null)
    ruleItem.ReferencedItemValue = eventEntity.Title;
}
```

Comment: And you are sure that `eventEntity` is not null in `FillRuleItem()`? Have you run it under the debugger? Also, `RuleItemResource` is a class not a struct, I assume? And I'm not sure that `.ToList()` in `FillReferenceValue()` is necessary.

Comment: @MatthewWatson There is a null check before the assignment in `FillRuleItem()`

Comment: @DGibbs Which is why I'm asking. If eventEntity is always null, no assignments will happen - which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger?

Comment: I have stepped in with the debugger and the eventEntity is not null

Comment: But what about my other question: Is `RuleItemResource` a struct?

Comment: Nope, it's a class, I know that Structs are treated as value types and in that case the value should not have been updated

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
rules.ForEach(showRule =>
    {
        var item = showRule;
        var showRuleResource = ToShowRuleResource(item);
        FillReferenceValue(showRuleResource);
        builder.LogDelete(item, showRuleResource.ToAuditLog(), "Logic Rule");
        });
```

Comment: Thinking maybe a closure? :)
Resharper does not indicate one but I will give it a try nevertheless

Comment: yeah it should be, read this blog post from Eric lippert: http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

Answer (score 1):

Start to dig from this function

```
private void FillRuleItem(RuleItemResource ruleItem)
```

It seems like this exspressiion

```
var eventEntity = uow.Context.Events.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == ruleItem.ReferencedItemId.Value);
```

is null.

Comment: checked it and it isn't null

Comment: Than, I do not see any criminal in your code. It can be some linq 'lazy loading', or some other codes pecific place in your code. Maybe showRuleResource.ToAuditLog() modifies values.